# subversion issue on mac os x

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, svn, httpd.conf

This exists in my httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /svn>

   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /Users/iirp/Sites/svn
   Allow from all
   #AuthType Basic
   #AuthName "Subversion repository"
   #AuthUserFile /Users/iirp/Sites/svn-auth-file
   #Require valid-user

</Location>
```

This is working file

When I change this to:

```
<Location /svn>

   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /Users/iirp/Sites/svn
   #Allow from all
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repository"
   AuthUserFile /Users/iirp/Sites/svn-auth-file
   Require valid-user

</Location>
```

and when I access my repository through URL, it gives me the authentication screen but after that screen my svn repository is not showing up correctly.

to see message that it gives to me is:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@example.com and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

Comment: Is there any information in the server error log?  You can look at it through Server Admin, or look at /var/log/httpd/error_log.  Also, I'd consider reworking the title and tags.  The problem sounds like one between apache and subversion, and doesn't appear to be specific to OS X.

Comment: Which versions are you running of OS X, subversion, and Apache?

Comment: One of the problem that I found in logs is: 

[Mon Jan 25 09:56:08 2010] [error] A subtree cannot specify a different DAV provider than its parent.

Comment: Can you please post your complete httpd.conf file here ... please post the data of all the include conf files also.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file /Users/iirp/Sites/svn-auth-file exist and is it readable by the user running the apache process? Check the permissions.

Comment: How can I find the user which running apache process ??

Comment: Run something like:
ps aux | grep apache
And the user running apache process will be in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Well, start from spliting task into smaller chunks

- Test with more bullet-proof config
- Test repository access (RO) without authebtication
- Test access in svn CLI client

### Hints per sub-tasks

## Config

```
<Location /svn/>
...
SVNParentPath /Users/iirp/Sites/svn/
```

## Anonymous access

```
Satisfy Any
```

## Access Testing

```
svn ls URL/REPO
```